# AD8232 - Measuring heart rate only if USB connector is touched. Grounding issue?

Tags: sensors, analog

#### TL;DR

I can read out my heart rate but I have to physically touch GND of the Arduino or else the signal is just noise.

#### Description

So I've started to play around with an Arduino and wanted to try out a heartrate sensor module (AD8232).

The following is the code I am using for this:

```c
const int CONNECTED_LED = 13;

const int LO_MINUS = 10;
const int LO_PLUS = 11;

bool disconnected = true;

enum State {
  CONNECTED,
  DISCONNECTED,
  LO_MINUS_DISCONNECTED,
  LO_PLUS_DISCONNECTED
};

enum State currentState = DISCONNECTED;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LO_MINUS, INPUT); // Setup for leads off detection LO +
  pinMode(LO_PLUS, INPUT); // Setup for leads off detection LO -
}


void loop() {
  State nextState = getState();

  if (nextState != currentState) {
    // Store the current state
    currentState = nextState;
    switch (nextState) {
      case DISCONNECTED:
        break;
      case LO_MINUS_DISCONNECTED:
        break;
      case LO_PLUS_DISCONNECTED:
        break;
    }
  }

  if (currentState == CONNECTED) {
    digitalWrite(CONNECTED_LED, HIGH);
    Serial.println(analogRead(A0));
  } else {
    digitalWrite(CONNECTED_LED, LOW);
    // Serial.println(-1);
  }

  delay(1);
}

State getState() {
  if (digitalRead(LO_MINUS) == 1 && digitalRead(LO_PLUS) == 1) {
    return DISCONNECTED;
  } else if (digitalRead(LO_PLUS) == 1) {
    return LO_PLUS_DISCONNECTED;
  } else if (digitalRead(LO_MINUS) == 1) {
    return LO_MINUS_DISCONNECTED;
  }
  return CONNECTED;
}
```

This is how I am connecting the boards (I double checked already twice)

```
AD8232  | Arduino UNO R3
------------------------
GND     |  GND
3.3v    |  3.3V
OUTPUT  |  A0
LD-     |  ~10
LD+     |  ~11
SDN     |  <not used>
```

[image]

I've followed this diagram for connecting the electrodes:

[image]

However, the result is a random signal *unless* I am touching the USB-connector or GND of the Arduino.

Below you can see the random signal and the moment I touched the connector. I noticed this by accident after hitting the reset button after wondering why on earth I only get this random signal:

[image]

So.. what's going on here? I have all three electrodes connected.

I've even tried to different modules (I bought the AD8232 two times) but I see the same issues with both modules.

If I touch something else e.g. a radiator (heater) then the signal becomes another kind of random. It only works touching the connector.

Since this appears like a grounding issue I checked for continuity from the GND pin of the AR8232 to the USB connector and continuity is given.

I'm not expert enough (yet) to see the problem. Anybody?

Comment: The Sparkfun tutorial https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/ad8232-heart-rate-monitor-hookup-guide/all  links to a sketch which reads also pins 10 and 11 (to detect a lead placement/connection problem) which you are ignoring.

Comment: @6v6gt I have updated my code to the actual thing I am using. Both electrodes appear to be connected (only occasionally I see a disconnect) but most of the time I can read values from `A0`. It's just that it does not resemple a heartbeat ECG at all.

Comment: You are powering the module with 3.3 volts ? If you are using a 5 volt Uno, it will see a maximum analog reading of about 675  for peaks in a 3.3 volt signal. There does seem to be some clipping in the top range of the signal.

Comment: Yes, according to those tutorials and the module, the power should be 3.3V. Nothing I see makes sense here. I've tried some sanity checks because I started thinking maybe I killed the Atmega accidentally but basic "LED blinking" is still working fine. I've absolutely no idea what this thing wants from me XD

Comment: Interestingly, your serial plotter shows a range of 50 units (samples?) on the X axis. That would be about 50ms which, for a heart beat in the normal range, is clearly not enough. The Serial plotter with IDE version 1.8.19 shows a range of 500 units on the X axis which appears to be the same as the Sparkfun tutorial screen shots. Try increasing the delay until the full scale is 3 or 4 normal heart beats or export the results say to Excel and plot there.

Comment: @6v6gt I've just updated the code and the plot. It's weird.. I've tried several delays now. A heartbeat appears to take around a secod (according to Google) so I've tried 1, 10, 25, 50 and 100 milliseconds using `delay()` but I always get chaotic results. As you can see above, the plot is not continuos as if the electrodes weren't connected at times. It's very jittery and I have no idea why. If I press the sensors on the skin the average jumps around but that's about it. Not sure where the problem is..

Comment: Your code has multiple Serial.println() statements which could be causing the gaps. You should have only one (new line character) after printing the data line ( consisting of the 0, the 750 and the analog value). If there is a bad result, just print say 10 instead of the analog value so only numerical data is sent to the plotter. Maybe add a fourth plot that toggles between say 700 and 740 every 100ms.

Comment: Tried that. The values jump around between 300 and 700 -I can't comprehend what's going on. Either it's completely broken somehow or the plotter is not working as intended. I do set the output pin 13 to HIGH in order to see if I am connected or not - this light is flickering so it still kind of appears as if the connections aren't not working properly. I've tested everything for continuity with the multimeter so I don't think there's an issue - except the pads maybe but I didn't use them before. The other day I tested a smoke sensor which worked just fine ..

Comment: You'll see that the limited number of sample that the IDE V2.x.x Serial plotter allows (by default) has got some criticism. Also there is also an apparent work around at the end of this thread: https://github.com/arduino/arduino-ide/issues/803. One of your problems is that if you increase the delay between samples enough to be display about 2 seconds of data (say 40ms), if only 50 samples are allowed, you may miss the interesting peaks.

Comment: I was about to post the same link as I've extended the number of samples to 5k now but the result is just pure garbage..  I just don't get what the hell is going on here...

Comment: @6v6gt Okay so.. I kind of got it working.. it only works if I touch the USB connector of the Arduino. Only discovered this by accident. Any idea what the problem is? It should work without that, shouldnt it?

Comment: Read through the reviews [here](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12650) and see if anything jumps out. The reviews titled "Great But Bad Pinout", "Poor Signal-to-Noise (SNR) ratio", "It actually works! for hobby purposes" all seem to contain something that may be relevant to your problem.

Comment: @timemage hm, not sure. It appears that I myself need to be grounded because after touching GND the signal is "okay". Yeah it's very noisy but you could compute the heart rate with that. My problem is that I don't understand why I have to be grounded in order to get a signal. I thought this measures voltage differences between two points given a reference point.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I'm saying that touching the USB shield could be having any number of effects related to the things mentioned in those reviews. I'm not able to test what happens if you run it on a battery or if you change the connections to the jack, or if you filter out your mains frequency. But you are.

Comment: I'm running it via the USB cable but I can try switching it to a battery. It's interesting because if I touch the radiator, then it will read a disconnect. If I touch the GND of the Arduino, it "works". Anything else is just random noise. Weird. ^^

Comment: Are you using electrodes that Sparkfun made or did you wire them yourself?

Comment: I am using the ones that came with the module itself.

Answer (score 1):

One of your three ECG leads is equivalent to (human)body ground, and it's not making contact. I spent too long making this image to explain it, which should help you a lot more than it will me.  I mean, I don't have the board in my hands, so I cannot see which lead goes to which pin.  You can, easily, with a multimeter testing for continuity between the:
RIGHT ARM,
RIGHT LEG,
LEFT ARM (RA, RL, LA) solder spots, and the tip, ring, barrel of the jack.
Something to keep in mind though is the headphone jack switch.  When the plug is physically inserted, this switch opens.  Again, I'm not there to guide your multimeter, so this image is the best I can do for you.  One of your leads is going to be a grounding lead. It may be the "black" one, it may be the (traditionally) "RL" one, it may be another one, i can't tell.

When you touch USB ground you are effectively replacing the body contact of the missing ground lead. I made these images for you to better understand it.  You should be able to fault find this in a few minutes via you MM and continuity testing.
[image: combined image of AD8232 with x-ray vision, and leads]

Comment: I've tested all three electrodes and I can detect continuity for each of them on the barrel of the jack. I don't think that's the problem. Like mentioned, I have two boards and two sets of electrodes and the issue is the same in both cases. However, is there any chance that it could be the power source? Right now I am powering it via USB cable from my PC. there might be a chance that I have to isolate the sensor and use a battery instead?

Comment: _I can detect continuity for each of them on the barrel of the jack_
erm... so....  all three electrodes are shorted to the barrel when plugged into the jack?  If that's the case you need to re-read what I wrote to you.

Comment: No, what I meant was RL, LA and RA are connected. The cables are fine.

Comment: I can't be any more helpful to you. The information you need is presented, and I cannot possibly be there to do it for you.